# Deleted localStorage and sessionStorage from browser when I work in locahost in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, local-storage, session-storage

I'm working in two fronts at the same time in Angular using localHost. I'm triying to save the localStorage or sessionStorage from Front X to Front Y . When they get to Front Y the localStorage or sessionStorage got deleted and I don't know why.

I'd like to know if I need to configurate some parameter into the angular.json or which is the file that helps me to persist the localstorage or sessionStorage in the browser. From front X I'm using window.open(frontYurl, '_self') to redirect to front y

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe to save the data in localStorage, and then the other domains ask the iframe for what we already saved.

```
    const domains = [
  "https://www.domain1.com",
  "https://www.domaine2.com"
]
window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
function messageHandler(event) {
  if (!domains.includes(event.origin))
    return;
  const { action, key, value } = event.data
  if (action == 'save'){
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
  } else if (action == 'get') {
    event.source.postMessage({
      action: 'returnData',
      key,
      JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key))
    }, '*')
  }
}
```

One of the other windows code will save a data
Uses postMessage to send a message event to the iframe.

```
 const data = doSomeThingToGetData()
const iframe = iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-id')
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
  action: 'save',
  key: 'keyForData',
  value: data
})
```

link:=>>> https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384